# How to loop li tags under ul tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is the html

```
<div class="field field--name-field-rdp-fc-sf-body field--type-text-long field--label-hidden">
  <div class="field__items">
    <div class="field__item even">
      <ul>
        <li>Facilities for Interactive white board or other audio visual display </li>
        <li>Holland Blinds to external windows.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

I just need each li in e variable

Here is my code

```
tag = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'field--name-field-rdp-fc-sf-body'})
ultag = tag.find('ul')
for i in ultag:
    e = i.find('li')
    print(e)
```

Comment: for i in tag[0].find_all('li'):
     e = i.text

Comment: It works, thank you very much!@SarthakNegi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the working code

```
tag = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'field--name-field-rdp-fc-sf-body'})
ultag = tag.find('ul')
for i in ultag.find_all('li'):
    e = i.text
    print(e)
```